# Ionic content not updating after callback from external plugin

Tags: callback, ionic3, components, updating

As part of the functionality of the app we are developing, when an android alarm is fired, a dialog box is to appear with an "Accept" or "Reject" button. Selecting reject does nothing, but selecting "Accept" triggers a callback from the plugin, which I have passed a function into. This function causes the ionic app to navigate to the root page of the app.

The issue I am having is, when I then navigate to another page after that where the user selects a value, and this value is displayed back to them and a button is enabled, the value display is not updating, and the button is not becoming enabled. Nothing seems to be updating.

What I have found is that pressing the back button on my android device will cause the page to update, which is not ideal.

This functionality works without the callback from the plugin.

What is happening here? And how do I fix it?

*Passing the function into the plugin.*

```
alarms_plugin.onAlarmRecieved = (alarmId) =>{
    this.events.publish('alarmRecieved', alarmId);
}
```

*Plugin-side functions*

```
alarmRecieved: function(alarmId){
   alarms_plugin.onAlarmRecieved(alarmId);
}

onAlarmRecieved: null
```

*Navigating to root page on alarmRecieved*

```
this.events.subscribe('alarmRecieved', (alarmId) =>{
   if(alarmId != 'TIMEOUT')
      this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix found by surrounding the `this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)` in `this.zone.run(..)`.

Supposedly calling navigation within a subscription event causes issues like I was having.